# ¿Cómo puedo crear un tunel entre un puerto tty y un puerto rfcomm?

Tags: linux, matlab, bluetooth, serialport

mi duda recae en que quiero que el comando de s**erialportlist de matlab (en linux v2021a)** me reconozca de alguna manera el puerto rfcomm, ya que al ejecutarlo de las 3 formas que sugiere la documentación solo me arroja el puerto de mi raspberry pico o del arduino; estoy usando rfcomm en linux para conectarme a un modulo bluetooth hc-05, si en matlab escribo la dirección del puerto directamente (/dev/rfcomm0) puedo establecer conexión, sin embargo he estado usando **serialportlist** en una app de matlab para generar una lista de los puertos disponibles, en windows no tiene problema por registrar todos los "com", pero en Linux no estoy seguro de como hacer que lo encuente, he notado que solo detecta los ttyXXX.
Intente crear un link simbolico entre un tty y el rfcomm pero aún así no logra enlistarlo.

*Gracias de antemano.*

Comment: Puedes probar con sudo ln -s  /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/ttyUSB0 tienes la respuesta correcta en el sitio https://askubuntu.com/questions/693147/set-up-bluetooth-rfcomm-as-a-virtual-serial-port-dev-tty0 simplemente busqué en google map /dev/rfcomm0 to tty

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Ya habia creado un link simbolico del rfcomm0 a un tty, pero matlab sigue sin detectarlo, solo me detecta /dev/ttyS0 y /dev/ttyS4 pero ninguno se corresponde con el que habia creado (/dev/ttyUSB10 o /dev/ttyS50)
pero aún así gracias por ayudar